# Spring, PostgreSQL : Intermediate table for many-to-many entries were automatically deleted

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, postgresql

- I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am using
  PostgreSQL as the database with Hibernate as the ORM tool. In the
  application I have a many-to-many mapping between two database
  tables(GroupAccount, GroupMembers)

  - A weird thing happened yesterday was, the intermediate
    table(MemberJunction) which links both these tables, the entries were
    deleted only for a single GroupAccount. When I checked the
    groupAccount, it was there, the members were also there, but because
    there was no entry, there was no linkage to retrieve the users with
    matching groupAccountId from the memberJunction.
  - The production is running debian Wheezy, and I am unable to find
    Postgresql logs in /var/logs/ directory, so I really don't know how
    to trace this issue. Has anyone experienced any similar problem? As
    from spring I don't even issue queries which can directly effect
    intermediate tables. I am posting my SQL code and the only one
    instance when I am querying with inner join. Any help would be nice
    as this happened on a production server.

SQL code :

```
CREATE TABLE groupaccount
(
  groupid numeric NOT NULL,
  groupname character varying,
  adminusername character varying,
  CONSTRAINT groupid PRIMARY KEY (groupid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE groupaccount
  OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE TABLE memberjunction
(
  memberid integer NOT NULL,
  groupid numeric NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT membergroupid PRIMARY KEY (memberid, groupid),
  CONSTRAINT groupaccount_memberjunction_fk FOREIGN KEY (groupid)
      REFERENCES groupaccount (groupid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT groupmembers_memberjunction_fk FOREIGN KEY (memberid)
      REFERENCES groupmembers (memberid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE memberjunction
  OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE TABLE groupmembers
(
  memberid integer NOT NULL,
  musername character varying,
  memberaccountstatus boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  memberactivated boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  groupaccid numeric NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  accesslevel boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
  sortorder numeric NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  notedeletenotify boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  notecreatenotify boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  canvascreatenotify boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  attachmentactionnotify boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  accounteditnotify boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  notecount integer DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT memberid PRIMARY KEY (memberid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE groupmembers
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Java Code to retrieve Members :

```
  @Override
    public List<GroupAccount> returnMemberIdWithMatchingUsername(String memberUsername) {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        org.hibernate.Query query = session.createQuery("Select ga From GroupAccount as " +
                "ga INNER JOIN ga.groupMembersSet as gm where gm.memberUsername=:memberUsername");
        query.setParameter("memberUsername",memberUsername);
        List<GroupAccount> groupAccountsList = query.list();
  // Other code ommited.
}
```

GroupAccountModel :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="groupaccount")
public class  GroupAccount {

 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinTable(name = "memberjunction", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "groupid")},
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "memberid")})
    private Set<GroupMembers> groupMembersSet = new HashSet<>();
}
```

GroupMembersModel :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="groupmembers")
public class GroupMembers {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groupMembersSet",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<GroupAccount> groupAccounts = new HashSet<>();

}
```

So, this way, when a groupMember is deleted the groupAccount does not get deleted and when a groupAccount is deleted, the subsequent members are deleted.

RemoveGroupMember :

```
   @Override
    public boolean removeGroupMember(int memberId) {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        GroupMembers groupMembers = (GroupMembers) session.get(GroupMembers.class, memberId);
        if(!(groupMembers == null)){
            for(GroupAccount groupAccount : groupMembers.getGroupAccounts()){
                groupAccount.getGroupMembersSet().remove(groupMembers);
                session.flush();
            }
            groupMembers.getGroupAccounts().clear();
            groupMembers.getOwnedcanvas().clear();
            session.flush();
            session.delete(groupMembers);
            session.flush();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Any idea what might have gone wrong, or how I can trace the issue. Thanks a lot.. :-)

Comment: Do you have cascade delete in your mapping ? Did you edit (removed) a item ?

Comment: @JEY  I have cascade delete in GroupAccount and not in GroupAccount, as the requirement was to delete entries when groupAccount was deleted, but the GroupAccount was not deleted or edited. Positive about that. Also, entries exist in groupAccount and GroupMembers, just not in MemberJunction.

Comment: I have cascade delete in GroupAccount and not in GroupAccount ??? what do you mean ?

Comment: @JEY : I have added some model code in main post, can you please check it. Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 0):

With this mapping when you update a GroupAccount more specificaly when you remove a item from the Set groupMembersSet from GroupAccount and save it ; The link between the edited GroupAccount and GroupMember is remove so the entry in the table memberjunction is removed. However the entries on both end are not removed. So if you do a clear() on your groupMembersSet and save all link are removed.

Comment: I am not calling a clear() from GroupAccount any time, It is only called when a groupMember is removed to remove the association. To be honest, I did not understand what I should I do to avoid this problem. I am pasting my code for removeMember in main post, kindly check it out.